# Facebook Connect for Qt

Tags: qt

I am trying to use the facebook API provided by Nokia Developer:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Facebook_Connect
I need to know what library or files should i include to connect to this API. And if you can provide me with any important guidelines it would be great.
Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you actually read the page you linked to? The first line has a link to the download location and the entire page is full of examples of how to use the API.

However, if you did follow the download link you'd see this:

> Facebook is deprecating the old REST api upon which this library is
>   based on. The new api is called facebook graph api and that should be
>   used, the rest api breaks all the time so its not a good idea to use
>   it. Please look at http://gitorious.org/qfacebook for a Qt
>   implementation of the new facebook graph API

Which makes your question somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry buddy but when you keep staring at the screen for 9 hours straight, this is what happens :P
Thanks for the note though the question was irrelevant as you said :)

Answer (score 3):

With Qt 5, you can now use the V-Play Facebook Qt Plugin.

It wraps the native Facebook SDK around a QML item and thus has the advantage that native login functionality and the whole Facebook Graph API is available cross-platform.

There is a free sample, documentation and tutorials available here: http://plugins.v-play.net/plugins/facebook/